# Finding the general term of a partial sum series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If $$s_n={5-{n \over 3^n}}$$ is the partial sum of the series of  $\sum_{k=1}^∞ a_k$,

can we find, a-) the general term of the series
             b-) the sum of the series?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$a_n=s_n-s_{n-1}$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k=\lim_{k\to\infty}s_k$$

Comment: So the sum is 5. What about the general term?

Comment: Have you tried my first hint?  It's pretty direct.

Comment: $$s_n=5- n/3^n $$ $$s_{(n-1)}=5-{(n-1)}/3^{(n-1)}$$

Comment: You actually want $s_{n\color{red}{-1}}$.

Comment: Sorry. I corrected it.

Comment: Subtract them and simplify.

Comment: I found $\sum_{n=1}^∞  a_n = \frac{(2n+3)}{3^n}$

Comment: That's clearly not right.  Surely the right side can't have $n$ in it.

Comment: Sorry. It was supposed to be $$a_n= (2n-3)/3^n$$

Comment: Well, there shouldn't be a summation, and then it's all good and well.

Comment: :-) No problem.

Answer (score 1):

$$s_{n+1}=\dfrac{10}{3}+\frac13s_n-\frac{1}{3^{n+1}}$$
with $\lim_\infty s_n=\ell$ then $\ell=\dfrac{10}{3}+\dfrac13\ell$ so $\ell=5$.

$a_n=s_{n}-s_{n-1}=\dfrac{2n-3}{3^n}$.

Comment: Thanks. What about the general term?

Comment: Hm, a strange way of doing.  If I may point out, you quietly assume the limit exists.

Comment: @MyGlasses lol, well, see if you can figure out why my hints work.

Comment: Well, it looks good now.